# Task Scheduler with 2 console apps in it not writing log file

Tags: c#, console, task, scheduler

I have a scheduled task with 2 console apps in it. When the task runs, it executes correctly, but neither of the log files are written to their respective directory. When I run the console apps manually (just double click on it) it runs, and produces a log file. If I take one of the console apps out of the schedule tasks, it runs and creates the respective log file... Any idea why 2 console apps in a scheduled task would not yield proper log (.txt) files?

Comment: What user do the scheduled tasks run as? Do they have permission to write to the needed file/directory?

Comment: how are you running two apps with one task?  What O/S?

Comment: Are you setting the working directory when you setup the task? If you do `dir /s logfilename.txt` from the root directory, does it perhaps find the log files in some default directory?

Comment: Task scheduler may not have privileges to access the log directory